# Could there be a TARDIS within a tardis?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

Suppose you took a TARDIS and flew it through the door of another, larger TARDIS. Because both are larger on the inside, is there any logical reason you couldn't store an entire universe-worth of TARDISes inside of one another?

Comment: I don't know about the second "logical reason" part of the question, so I won't write this up as an answer, but the TARDIS-within-a-TARDIS thing has actually happened, in the original series episodes "The Time Monster" and "Logopolis" as well as the modern series "minisode" [Space / Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_/_Time).

Comment: It wouldn't have to "fly through the door", it could just materialize inside.  Or outside.  Or both at the same time.

Comment: In Russia, you don't nest TARDIS. TARDIS nests you.

Comment: Yes, **but** if the two TARDISes attempt to materialize at the same time and space it results in a [***time ram***](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Time_ram).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe?

This has actually happened, in a manner of speaking; in "Logopolis", a Fourth Doctor story aired in 1981, the Master materialized his TARDIS inside (but also outside) the Doctor's:

[image]

> (The Doctor enters the police box and finds himself in a more dimly lit console room. Adric has of course followed him.)
>
> **Doctor:** Get back to the Tardis.
>
> **Adric:**  But this is the Tardis.
>
> **Doctor:** A Tardis, perhaps.
>
> **Adric:** It looks just like yours.
>
> **Doctor:** Yes, down to the last detail.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Season 18 Episode 7: "Logopolis"</sup>

But it caused a bit of a problem:

> **Doctor:** Another instrumentation failure.
>
> **Adric:** A gravity bubble?
>
> **Doctor:** No.
>
> (The Doctor hits the console and it starts beeping.)
>
> **Doctor:** Definitely a gravity bubble. Pretty local too, by the look of it.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Season 18 Episode 7: "Logopolis"</sup>

Presumably, an infinite nesting doll of TARDISes would cause the gravity bubble to increase exponentially in size. What effect this might have on any of the TARDII, or on the planet they were sitting on, is unclear.

On the other hand, the Doctor has also demonstrated the ability to reduce the TARDIS' exterior mass:

> **Doctor:** Clara, I need you to pick up the Tardis. Carefully. It should be possible. I've adjusted the relative gravity.
>
> **Clara:** You mean you've made it lighter.
>
> **Doctor:** Clara, it's always lighter. If the Tardis were to land with its true weight, it would fracture the surface of the Earth.
>
> <sup>*Doctor Who* Series 8 Episode 9: "Flatline"</sup>

Presumably it then *might* be possible, but it's unclear.

Comment: Also the pair of 11th Doctor shorts Space/Time, where the TARDIS materialised within itself (but with a small time discrepancy), causing some issues.